# What kind of wood is recommended for replacing kitchen cabinet shelving?

Tags: kitchens, shelving

We have kitchen cabinets with removable plywood shelves.  They are 1/2" thick and 10.25" wide.  The lengths are 19.25" (short) and 31.25" (long).  We want two more short, and one more long one.

They look like a standard size.  Does anyone sell pre-cut shelves like this, or do I have to buy a 2' X 4' X 1/2" sheet of plywood and get it cut?

Googling did not reveal any pre-cut.

**EDIT**: I am in San Francisco. We went to a local hardware store and they did not have any good equipment. They said they would have to "hand cut" it (circular saw?) because they do not have space for power tools in their stores.  We are going to try [Discount Builders Supply](http://www.discountbuilderssupplysf.com/).

Comment: Just bare plywood shelves?  Not sealed or anything?

Comment: They look bare to me.

Answer (score 2):

You did not say where you are located so direct advice is not possible....but:  Here in the USA many of the "big box" stores will happily cut a plywood panel up into the sizes that you require. Just commit yourself to the purchase of the 4' x 8' panel and they can cut you three or four shelves to the sizes you need.

These stores have a special setup called a panel saw that makes cutting up panels a piece of cake. Do stress that you have to have close tolerance on the dimensions of each piece so it comes out proper for you. Sometimes the young folks employed at these stores will think that "within a quarter" of an inch is good enough.

Also note that if you go to the shelf at the store and buy the ready cut 2' x 4' pieces be aware that:

1. Usually four of the 2x4 pre trimmed panels costs more than a whole
   4x8 panel.
2. You will get 3 shelves out of each 2x4 piece instead of 1 with lots of waste.
3. The large panel may have a nice sized chunk left over that you can
   take home for a future DIY project.
4. There may be reluctance on their part to cut the small panels for
   you.

Comment: bring to the store one of each size to show the employee and to verify that the newly cut shelves are the right size.

Comment: @mike - Good suggestion!!

Comment: Thanks for the term "panel saw", that will be good to ask for.  We are only going to get the 2x4 because we only want two short and one long shelf.

Comment: By the way, this worked! Discount Builder Supply had a panel saw. Thank you!